# shiny Rmarkdown multiplication result to textOutput()

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I'm learning the `Shiny` way to do things. I want to embed `Shiny` code into a `Rmarkdown` document. I'm looking at the `shiny-cheatsheet` but has the normal way to built the application; `ui and server`. How to make this code work in `Rmarkdown`

````
```{r , echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
    numericInput(inputId = "amount",
                 label = "Enter Amount",
                 value = 1)
)
result <- renderText({
            input$amount * 3.025
        })
textOutput(outputId = "result")
```
````

Comment: Check the YAML option `runtime: shiny`

Comment: It is `runtime: shiny`

Comment: I misunderstood you there. Well the snippet works for me in a Rmd document with the header only containing  `output: html_document` and `runtime: shiny`

Comment: Do the multiplication works?

Comment: The multiplication doesn't work. I know that the `numericInput` does work but not the multiplication in the `renderText`.

Comment: Oh boy. It's too late for me today :D.....try `output$result <- ...`